# Mysql, Gaps and islands with a twist

Tags: mysql, sql

So here's my issue : I have the following table :

```
id | date       | am_in | pm_in
 1 | 2020-09-01 |     0 |     0
 2 | 2020-09-02 |     0 | 12345
 3 | 2020-09-03 | 12345 | 12345
 4 | 2020-09-04 |     0 | 12345
 5 | 2020-09-05 | 12345 |     0
 6 | 2020-09-06 | 12345 |     0
```

id is unique but has no relation to the date in the actual database (id 101 is not 100 days after id 1)

I must find every consecutive half days with 12345 in am_in or pm_in.
eg :

```
from 2020-09-02 pm to 2020-09-03 pm
from 2020-09-04 pm to 2020-09-05 am
from 2020-09-06 am to 2020-09-06 am
```

So far my query is the following  :

```
WITH t AS ( 
    SELECT `date` d,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY `date`) i 
    FROM test 
    where ( `am_in`=12345 or `pm_in`=12345) 
    and `date`>=CURDATE() 
    GROUP BY `date` 
    ) 
    SELECT MIN(d) as `from`,MAX(d) as `to` 
    FROM t 
    GROUP BY DATE_ADD(d, INTERVAL -i DAY) 
    having `to`>=CURDATE()
```

It would work with only one row, but it this case it does not work because it returns islands where either one of am_in or pm_in equal to 12345.

```
from 2020-09-02 to 2020-09-06
```

I tried every possible variations I could think of but nothing was good.

Any help or idea is appreciated !

Thanks in advance !

Comment: It might not be 100 days after, but it *is* after, right?

Comment: looks like mssql not mysql, right?

Comment: @Strawberry not necessarily, that's why i used ```ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY `date`) i```  in the select

Comment: Are all dates represented, or can there be a date with no entry between 2 others?

Comment: @GarrGodfrey nope it is mysql (mariadb on my test setup that is).
All dates are not necessarily represented

Comment: Isn't `from 2020-09-02 pm to 2020-09-03 pm` equals to a full day?

Comment: @tcadidot0 I think it is 3 consecutive half days in this case. tough problem

Comment: So, it's group by consecutive half days? Since `2020-09-04` doesn't have `am_in`, it breaks the chain and recount again. I kinda understand it now

Comment: Normalize your data to `(date, am_pm, in)` (use UNION) - and you will obtain classic gaps-and-islands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unpivot the data and then use gaps-and-islands.  I would count half days since some canonical date:

```
with cte as (
      select datediff(date, '2000-01-01') * 2 as n, date, am_in as i
      from t
      union all
      select datediff(date, '2000-01-01') * 2 + 1 as n, date, pm_in
      from t
     )
select min(date),
       (case when min(n) % 2 = 0 then 'am' else 'pm' end),
       max(date),    
       (case when max(n) % 2 = 0 then 'am' else 'pm' end)
from (select cte.*,
             row_number() over (order by n) as seqnum
      from t
      where i = 12345
     ) t
group by (n - seqnum)
```

Comment: Wow awesome ! Thank you. 
I took the liberty to change it a little bit, removed the "case" part as a random number that's either odd or even to determine am or pm is sufficient for me. I like your way to do the gaps and islands better than mine as well. 
Thanks a lot !